# Joomla ajax call onclick event to call helper method in component

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla

My case is the following:
I need to call a php helper method within the view/edit.php of my component in order to validate the value of a textbox against the database. I have read a lot of threads regarding ajax calls within joomla but have not managed yet to get it working.

The method in the **helper.php** is `MyClass::CheckName($name)`

In the view **view/edit.php** I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
    {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "helper.php",
                data: ????
                success: function(data){
                    do something...       
                }
                error: function(data){
                    ...do something else        
                }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I am new to joomla (component) development so I could do with some good relevant examples/snippets on the subject as well as guidance to a best practice approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to makes AJAX calls as you've described.  I've clearly outlined what I believe to be the most straight forward with [this answer on joomla.stackexchange.com](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/146/what-is-the-proper-way-to-make-an-ajax-call-in-component/2541#2541)